# How can you crop an image and output from a Matrix field?

Tags: templating, matrix, image-transforms

Trying to output a matrix field image so that it crops the thumbnail. However, I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's what I have:

```
{% for block in entry.servicesItems.type('images') %}
    <div class="col">

        {% if block.image|length %}

            {% set thumb = {
                mode: 'crop',
                width: 229,
                height: 172,
                quality: 75,
                position: 'center-center'
            } %}

            <a href="images/{{ block.image.first }}.jpg">
                <img src="images/{{ block.image.first('thumb') }}.jpg" alt="{{ block.alt }}" width="{{ block.image.first.getWidth(thumb) }}" height="{{ block.image.first.getHeight(thumb) }}">

                <div id="lightbox-title">
                    <h2>{{ block.imageTitle }}</h2>
                    <p>{{ block.imageContent }}</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `.first` on an Asset field, that's going to return an [AssetFileModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/AssetFileModel).

Change the relevant part of your code to this:

```
{# grab the first image #}
{% set image = block.image.first() %}

{# link to the full sized version #}
<a href="{{ image.getUrl('thumb') }}">

    {# generated the transformed thumbnail version #}
    <img src="{{ image.getUrl('thumb')}}" alt="{{ block.alt }}" width="{{ image.getWidth('thumb') }}" height="{{ image.getHeight('thumb') }}">

    <div id="lightbox-title">
        <h2>{{ block.imageTitle }}</h2>
        <p>{{ block.imageContent }}</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: That did the trick...you know if there's a way to zoom on the image crop?

Comment: Some of the transforms will scale, but no zooming. http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/image-transforms#defining-transforms-from-the-control-panel

Comment: I'll find some css.  Thanks for the help.